# How to make the text inside my <Col> vertical align follow the size of the <img>? (AntDesign)

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

[This is what it currently looks like butI wish all the details which is title,price and quantity and be vertically align center to the image while keeping the details inside the column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8Rf7.png)

How make the height of  similar to the height of the  i put in which both is inside the  tag?

I am using Ant Design

```
<Row>
  <Col
    span={6}
    style={{
      fontWeight: 600,
      paddingLeft: 10,
      alignItems: "center",
      textAlign: "center",
      verticalAlign: "center",
      justifyContent: "center"
    }}
  >
    <img
      style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
      src={
        "https://www.needen.com/files/model_specifications/2015/8/31/121154/121154_big.jpg?1441032179"
      }
    />
  </Col>

  <Col
    span={6}
    style={{
      display: "flex",
      paddingLeft: 10,
      alignItems: "center",
      verticalAlign: "middle"
    }}
  >
    <h5 style={{ verticalAlign: "middle" }}>T-Shirt 1</h5>
  </Col>

  <Col
    type="flex"
    span={4}
    style={{
      minHeight: 100,
      fontWeight: 600,
      verticalAlign: "middle",
      textAlign: "center",
      alignItems: "center",
      justifyContent: "center"
    }}
  >
    RM 19.90
  </Col>

  <Col
    span={4}
    style={{
      minHeight: 100,
      fontWeight: 600,
      textAlign: "center",
      alignItems: "center",
      verticalAlign: "middle"
    }}
  >
    2
  </Col>

  <Col
    span={4}
    style={{
      minHeight: 100,
      fontWeight: 600,
      textAlign: "right",
      paddingRight: 10,
      alignItems: "center",
      verticalAlign: "middle"
    }}
  >
    <p
      style={{ height: "100%", verticalAlign: "middle", alignItems: "center" }}
    >
      RM 38.90
    </p>
  </Col>
</Row>
```

The whole row should be same size with the image height and the words should be vertical align center...

Comment: You have `<Col>` nested in another `<Col>`. That is not how it's supposed to be.

Comment: Ok edited and updated my code, but how to solve the original problem?

Comment: Try **not** to style the `<Col>` nodes directly (at least no layout stuff) and instead put a separate `<div>` in them you can style. Also, try to use every possibility Ant gives you before fixing things with your own CSS. Maybe `<Row type="flex" align="center">` helps?

Comment: Show an image\example of your expected behavior...

Comment: Oh sorry for that, I have updated the image, thanks for helping

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refer to [`Grid` API](https://ant.design/components/grid/):

```js
<Row
  type="flex"
  style={{ alignItems: "center" }}
  justify="center"
  gutter={10}
/>
```

[image]

Example:

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Row
      type="flex"
      style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}
      justify="center"
      gutter={10}
    >
      <Col>
        <img
          style={{ width: 100, border: '1px solid palevioletred' }}
          alt="white-shirt"
          src={
            'https://www.needen.com/files/model_specifications/2015/8/31/121154/121154_big.jpg?1441032179'
          }
        />
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <Row
          type="flex"
          gutter={10}
          style={{ alignItems: 'center', border: '1px solid palevioletred' }}
        >
          <Col>T-Shirt 1</Col>
          <Col>RM 19.90</Col>
          <Col>2</Col>
          <Col>RM 38.90</Col>
        </Row>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Q-57071769-AlignItems]

Comment: I use your code and it works great! But how can I wish that they can align with the column not just centered (I had uploaded a image as an update in my question) .. can it be done? since I am not familiar with flex

Comment: Please just ask another question

Comment: This answer is outdated. There is no more "type" property for rows.

Comment: True! Always refer to the newest version